# How to use model binder in .net core mvc with Ajax Post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm new to .net core MVC and am trying to execute an Ajax post similar to .net framework MVC. I'm simply trying to POST a single int value to the controller action below. The Ajax call hits the controller, but the action parameter is always 0. I verified that the correct integer value is being sent in the Ajax request payload. What am I missing?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Ajax_GenerateSecretNum([FromBody]int lower)
    {

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Ajax_GenerateSecretNum", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { lower: lower },
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Ajax_GenerateSecretNum", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',               
                data: { "lower": lower, "upper": upper },
                success: function (response) {

                }   
            });
```

Changing my jQuery ajax to the above sample solved the issue. I'm not sure why, but it looks like specifying the extra ajax parameters caused the values to fail model binding. After changing the ajax, I was also able to remove the [FromBody] attribute from the controller action.

Comment: For some reasons I can't explain, this is the only thing that worked for me. Also, the big hint was data:{"lower": lower} if lower is an int

Answer (score 2):

You could create a model (DTO) for the controller parameter and use `JSON.stringify()` on your data before posting to the controller.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Ajax_GenerateSecretNum", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ lower: lower }),
    success: function (response) {

    }
});

public class ModelDto
{
    public int Lower { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Ajax_GenerateSecretNum([FromBody]ModelDto model)
{
    // model.Lower should contain your int
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { "Property1": "value1", "Property2": "value2"},
        url: "@Url.Action("Ajax_GenerateSecretNum", "Home")",
        success: function (data) {
            //success login
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error' + data.status);
        }
    });
```

Controller will look like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ajax_GenerateSecretNum(ModelClass modelClass)
{
    //You logic will be here
}
```